# Vertex Ai AutoML Endpoint Error: "TypeError: predict_tabular_classification_sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instances'"

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

- Google Cloud AutoML tabular classification model created.
- Followed instructions for Python in Sample Request Code.
- Error:  TypeError: predict_tabular_classification_sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instances'

[Sample Request Code provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr6Sp.png)

[Sample Request Code in Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1kd.png)

[Error at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkvgH.png)